# Where is WCF Data Services in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services

I watched [EF4.1 and n-tier application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh272554) video for Julie Lerman,
she added a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application project in the solution (VS 2010). After that  she added a new item, **WCF Data Service**.
I can not find this item in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. Could you please help me? Is this a limitation in the express 2012 version?

[Here is an image of what I can see in the Add New Item form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kceKI.png)

---

I can't post answer my question, so:
I should intall "WCF Data Services 5.2 RTM Tools Installer"
More details on WCF Data services blog.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install "WCF Data Services 5.2 RTM tools installer". For the VS pro and ultimate versions, we chain in the installer for "WCF data Services - 5.0". For the express editions, customers need to install the version they need.

One thing to note - even in Pro/Ultimate editions, the version that gets installed is 5.0. For newer features (like the new JSON format), customers will require to install the latest bits so that they can get all the new code generation features.

Thanks
Pratik